# Why in PHP 7.2.19 when error_reporting() is set to 0 the subsequent ini_set() is ignored?

Tags: php

Why PHP 7.2.19 when error_reporting() is set to 0 the subsequent ini_set() is ignored. Not a word about this behavior in PHP Docs. Is this a bug or very poor documenting?

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set(log_errors, '1');  //This directive is ignored and nothing is logged
```

However, the statement below works if display_errors is set to  "off" in php.ini

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set(log_errors, '1');  //This directive is executed
```

Comment: Why are you expecting any errors to be displayed when error reporting is tunred off?

Comment: How do you know that the `ini_set` function is ignored? How would you notice any difference if all the errors are switched off? If the errors are switched of there is nothing to display anyway.

Comment: @ B001 Perhaps I want to turn off all errors in the script except for  logging. @Dharman If ini_set() is issued afte the error_repoting() it should superseed it and if this is not the case then it should be documented in the php Docs.

Comment: It is documented. See [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). One tells you which errors PHP should report the other tells you whether to show them to end users or not. Two different things. There is also [`log_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) - which will log the error into a file on the server if switched on.

Comment: you can post an offtopic 'question' complaining about the php documentation, or you could actually try and make it better by contributing: https://www.php.net/get-involved.php

Comment: @Dharman - No, directive log_errors will not log any errors if the error_reporting is set to 0. – Jimski 24 mins ago –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain this in a form of a dialogue:

When `error_reporting(0)`

- **PHP:** Ooopsie-daisy, you have made a mistake in your code. Let me check the `error_reporting` level to see if you want to be informed about this.
- **You:** No, ignore all errors/warnings/information. I have set `error_reporting` to 0. Not a word to anyone about what happened, understood?

When `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

- **PHP:** Ooopsie-daisy, you have made a mistake in your code. Let me check the `error_reporting` level to see if you want to be informed about this.
- **You:** Yes, tell me everything!
- **PHP:** Ok, let me know how you would like to be informed about what's happened.
- **You:** I have set `log_errors` to 1. Could you just put all errors into a file and I will check them when I have some free time.
- **PHP:** Sure. Would you like me to show the same error to the user in the browser too?
- **You:** No. The user does not need to know. I set `display_errors` to 0.

Comment: This behavior of the function is inconsistent and not explained in the Documentation. Poor logic and poor documentation on part of PHP developers.

Comment: Consistency is a virtue in programming. If ini_set(), when issued subsequently, can superseed one setting of error_reporting() then it should override any other setting of this function. – Jimski 5 mins ago

Comment: You do realise that nothing is overriding anything here? They are all ini settings and all 3 of them have a different meaning and a purpose.

Comment: Poor choice of words, I meant superseded not override. And while ini_set() is not overriding the error_reporting() directly  it is overriding the settings in php.ini

Comment: Yes, correct, that is the whole purpose of that function.